# Is there a way to include a header in every compilation unit without modifying every source file?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, include

Given the following:

- large project with thousands of C++ source files
- no common header file (no one header that's included in every source file)
- said project is compiled with g++ and managed by make

Is there any way to include a definition (e.g. macro) into every compilation unit without modifying every source file to include a new header file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From man gcc:

> *-include file*
>
> Process file as if "#include "file"" appeared as the first line of
>     the primary source file.  However, the first directory searched for
>     file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory 
>     containing the main source file.  If not found there, it is
>     searched for in the remainder of the "#include "..."" search chain
>     as normal.
>     If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in
>     the order they appear on the command line.

Comment: Perfect! I was apparently only reading "man g++" which does not contain full documentation.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the "-D" gcc command line option.

Example: `gcc -ansi -Wall -Dblah='mymacrohere()' blah.cpp`

See also: [GCC Manual, Command Line options, Preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)