# C++ constexpr function to test preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, autoconf, constexpr

In my C++ project (I use autotools) I have a class with `begin()` and `end()` member functions, and I want to optionally include `cbegin()` and `cend()`, if and only if C++11 is supported.

I test C++11 support using an M4 file from the Autoconf Archive. It's a macro which defines HAVE_CXX11 if supported, otherwise it doesn't define it.

The C way to do what I want is:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CXX11
    const_iterator cbegin () const;
    const_iterator cend () const;
#endif
```

But I want to do some things in the C++ way. In this case I can use `std::enable_if` to optionally allow `cbegin` and `cend`. Like this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CXX11
#define MY_HAVE_CXX11 true
#else
#define MY_HAVE_CXX11 false

constexpr bool have_cxx11 ()
{
    return MY_HAVE_CXX11;
}

/* Now use have_cxx11() with std::enable_if */
```

This works fine with a single specific macro, but what if I want to *automate* it for any given macro? In other words, what I want is to **get a boolean indicating whether a given macro is defined.**

I see two options:

1. Have a specific function for each macro
2. Have a single function

Example for 1:

When autoconf defines its variable HAVE_CXX11, it will also define have_cxx11() to return true or false depending on whether the HAVE_CXX11 autoconf variable (not the macro constant) is defined to 0 or 1.

Example for 2:

The can be a function `macro_is_defined()` which returns a boolean, e.g. `macro_is_defined(HAVE_CXX11)` will return `true` when I build my C++11 project.

I tried to find a way to implement these ideas in pure C++, but found none. I had to make a single line of code expand into a block of preprocessor directives, which IIRC is impossible. What should I do? And is it a good idea to try doing things the C++ way like I try, or it's too much?

**EDIT:**

autoheader creates `#undef`s for all macros, even the ones which eventually get commented out. So I could write a script which scans config.h and generates a constexpr function for each macro. The question is where it should be inserted in the build process and how it's called.

Comment: If you're OK with function macro_is_defined(HAVE_CXX11), then what's wrong with having macro MACRO_IS_DEFINED(HAVE_CXX11)? Then you can see how trivial it is to implement it.

Comment: @biocomp How would I implement such a macro? I'd need to use #ifdef to define MACRO_IS_DEFINED to true or false, but I can't make a single line expand into 5 lines of preprocessor directives

Comment: Uhm, how are you planning to use `constexpr` without C++11 support?

Comment: @catscradle Good point. I'm not. The C++11 support is just an example. Instead I could be checking for support of some library, or C++14 support in the future (while assuming C++11 and freely using constexpr). Or I could simply drop constexpr and the question remains relevant, limiting usage to realtime i.e. can't use with enable_if

Comment: Ok, and how would you use `std::enable_if` in your `cbegin` example?

Comment: @catscradle If I use constexpr then I can use enable_if like in the examples here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if. I could use enable_if on the return type of cbegin(). Without constexpr of course it's impossible

Comment: @fr33domlover Well, have you tried it? Because I don't think it works the way you think it does...

Comment: @catscradle No, but I trust the examples I linked to. Anyway it's just a specific example. I'm interested in generally being able to use the constexpr values, e.g. in boolean parameters of templates. So enable_if is just a specific example of the general idea

Comment: @fr33domlover you're right, my bad. Can't really define macro with #ifdef inside.

Comment: @biocomp Indeed... check the edit, I'm considering to write a function-generator running at configure time.

Comment: @catscradle This is how enable_if can be used with cbegin(), check the example in the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363822/compile-time-conditional-member-function-call-in-c

Comment: Just wondering:  is there any particular reason you don't want cbegin() and cend() in pre-C++11 code?  It usually doesn't hurt to have them (at least until someone wants to change containers).

Comment: @Nevin No, I decided to include them in my code even without C++11 :-) But the original question still stands

Comment: If a macro is defined as nothing, it expands to nothing.  If it is undefined, it expands as itself.  What you need is an expression where a blank does one thing, and any other identifier does something else.  Macros defined as an arbitrary string can be attacked elsewhere...

Comment: I wrote a nuts-and-bolts sort of answer to the Q. and deleted it when I realized this. The autoconf macro that defines `HAVE_CXX`, or not, is `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` and it defines `HAVE_CXX` if the compiler supports `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` or the `gnu` variants. So if `HAVE_CXX` turns out not defined then you can't possibly do any `std::enable_if` SFINAEs based on whether or not the macro is defined because in that case the compiler doesn't have `std::enable_if` anyhow.

Comment: @MikeKinghan You're right, but HAVE_CXX11 is a specific case. Assume I was testing for some other macro, not related to language features

Comment: @fr33domlover OK, I'll generalize it and repost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> autoheader creates #undefs for all macros, even the ones which eventually get 
>   commented out. So I could write a script which scans config.h and generates a 
>   constexpr function for each macro. The question is where it should be inserted 
>   in the build process and how it's called.

If you are satisfied (as I think your should be) that you can't accomplish the 
goal purely in C++ and will need some custom build support as per quote, then 
perhaps you are seeing one complication that isn't there.

I don't see that you need a *function*, either one per `HAVE_XXXX`-macro
or one for all `HAVE_XXXX`-macros, to tell you whether a given macro is
defined. I mean I see no reason why you should start by pondering how this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_XXXX
#define MY_HAVE_XXXX true
#else
#define MY_HAVE_XXXX false
#endif

constexpr bool have_xxxx ()
{
    return MY_HAVE_XXXX;
}
```

can be automated for all `HAVE_XXXX`-macros. You could replace that either in 
a `.h` file or a `.cpp` with:

```
#ifdef HAVE_XXXX
bool const have_XXXX = true;
#else
bool const have_XXXX = false;
#endif
```

In C++, `const` objects have internal linkage by default, so even in a header
file these definitions run no risk of multiple definition errors at link time.

In that light, a customized build solution would execute a script to parse the 
`config.h` and write out a header file, say `config_aux.h` that includes `config.h`
and contains:

```
#ifdef HAVE_XXXX
bool const have_xxxx = true;
#else
bool const have_xxxx = false;
#endif
```

for each `HAVE_XXXX`.

You ensure that `config_aux.h` is built as a prerequisite of everything else
and then for all your compiles you ensure that `config_aux.h` is pre-included
by the compiler in every translation unit. The way to do that is to pass g++
the option:

```
-include config_aux.h
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/571589/1362568)

On the other hand, I think you're on the wrong track as to how you
would actually use `have_xxxx` to do what you want.

In a comment you have linked to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11364011/1362568),
indicating that you see that `enable-if`-SFINAE technique as a model for 
statically enabling or disabling a member function, by making it a
template member function with two SFINAE alternatives: one that would be chosen
by template resolution when `have_xxxx` is true, and one that will be chosen 
when `have_xxxx` is false.

That's not actually a model for your requirement. It shows how to
SFINAE a member function between one implementation that does the business
*when applicable per template parameter* and alternative implementation
that is a no-op.

But you don't want your program to *do nothing* if
a statically disabled member function gets called. You want such a call to
*cause a compilation error*. E.g. you don't want a call to `T::cbegin()`
to be a no-op when `HAVE_CXX11` is false: you want the call to be a
compiletime error.

So you don't need SFINAE, but you do need the member function to become
a template member function, because template resolution is the only
mechanism for statically enabling or disabling it within the same class
(not counting the old `#ifdef` way).

It might seem that the obvious solution is illustrated
in the following program:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define HAVE_XXXX 1 // Pretend we get this from autoconf

// Pretend we get this from config_aux.h
#ifdef HAVE_XXXX
bool const have_xxxx = true;
#else
bool const have_xxxx = false;
#endif

struct X
{
    void a(){}

    template<typename R = typename std::enable_if<have_xxxx,void>::type>
    R b() {}
};


int main()
{
    X x;
    // x.b();
    return 0;
}
```

With `HAVE_XXXX` defined it compiles, implementing both `X::a` and
`X::b`. It *could* make the commented-out call to `X::b`.
But if `HAVE_XXXX` were *not* defined then any call to `X::b`
would require instantation of that member function with `std::enable_if<false,void>`
and that would not compile.

But just edit the program so that `HAVE_XXXX` is *not* defined and rebuild it.

The build fails:

> error: ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if’ does not name a type

even though the program still makes no calls to `X::b`. You can't build
the program at all unless `HAVE_XXXX` is defined.

The problem here is that the compiler *can* always
evaluate `have_xxxx` without resort to template resolution. So it does;
so it *always* discovers that error.

To prevent this, you would need the condition of the `enable_if` to depend on
a template parameter of the function, so it will only be evaluated in
template resolution, but still always to be true [false], *if* it is evaluated,
as long `have_cxxx` is true [false]. Anything to that effect will do and a 
condition like:

```
!std::is_same<R,R>::value || have_xxxx
```

might come to mind. But:

```
template<
    typename R = 
    typename std::enable_if<(!std::is_same<R,R>::value || have_xxxx),void>::type
>
R b() {}
```

will not compile any which way, for the elementary reason that it attempts
to use the template parameter `R` to define the default type of itself.

But as `std::enable_if` has this irrelevant snag, why resort to it at all? 
A `static_assert` of a suitable condition within the body of `X::b` will do just was well. 
Diagnostically, it will do better. So instead define `X::b` like:

```
    template<typename R = void>
    R b() {
        static_assert(!std::is_same<R,R>::value || have_xxxx,
            "X::b is unimplemented without XXXX support");
    }
```

Now, the program will compile whether `HAVE_XXXX` is defined or not and
when it is defined you can also uncomment the call to `X::b`. But
if `HAVE_XXXX` is *not* defined, and you also uncomment the call to `X::b`,
then the member function gets instantiated; R is defined; the condition of the
`static_assert` is evaluated, found false, and the `static_assert`
fires. This is the outcome you want.

Answer (score 3):

> In other words, what I want is to get a boolean indicating whether a
> given macro is defined.

This is possible using `constexpr` string comparison and a macro:

```cpp
#define _eval(x) #x // extra round of macroexpansion (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13074537/12808416)
#define is_defined(x) _is_defined(#x, _eval(x))
```

The form of the `_is_defined()` helper function depends on the C++ version:

### C++20

`constexpr string` is (at long last!) [part of the standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0980r1.pdf), although, as of 2023, compiler support is still weak.  The code below only works with GCC ≥12 and the `-std=c++2b` option, for example.

```cpp
#include <string>
using std::string;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool _is_defined(T s1, T s2) { return string(s1) != string(s2); }
```

### [C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762940/12808416)

```cpp
#include <string_view>

constexpr bool _is_defined(const char s1[], const char s2[]) {
    return std::string_view(s1) != s2;
}
```

### [C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27491087/12808416)

```cpp
constexpr bool isequal(char const *one, char const *two) {
    return (*one && *two) ? (*one == *two && isequal(one + 1, two + 1)) : (!*one && !*two);
}
constexpr bool _is_defined(const char s1[], const char s2[]) { return !isequal(s1, s2); }
```

#### strcmp()

[Some compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520781/compiler-differences-for-use-of-strcmp-in-a-constexpr) provide this shortcut:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
constexpr bool _is_defined(const char s1[], const char s2[]) {
     return strcmp(s1, s2); // true if unequal
}
```

---

`is_defined()` in use:

```cpp
#define FOO
#define BAR 0 
#define BAZ 1 
#define INDIRECT FOO
#undef UNDEFINED
#define BAD BAD

static_assert(is_defined(FOO), "Empty but true");
static_assert(is_defined(BAR), "Defined true");
static_assert(is_defined(BAZ), "Defined false");
static_assert(is_defined(INDIRECT), "Expands to another token, still true");
static_assert(!is_defined(UNDEFINED), "False");
static_assert(!is_defined(BAD), "Extensionally indistinguishable from undefinedness");
```

It works by comparing the 'stringified' versions of `x` and whatever it macroexpands to.  These will only be equivalent if `x` is not a defined preprocessor token (or if it expands to itself, as in the 'BAD' case).

---

- **29 Mar 23** Edited to add other tests of C-string equality.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you misunderstood when `std::enable_if` can be used.
to use it, your function (or class) **must** be a template! so, you **can't** use this trick for non template functions. and I think `cbegin()` and `cend()` do not needed to be templates...

actually, the only generic solution is to use preprocessor somehow. and usually it is used like you mention in your first code snippet. so, IMO, you over-engineering here :)

and btw, it is not needed to define `constexpr` functions... all that you really need is to define some type (struct) public from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` (or more generic way just use `std::integral_constant<bool, (some-boolean-expression-here)>`), so it can be used as `enable_if` condition (by accessing a nested `value` member).

Comment: You can "force" it to be a template function by adding a dummy template parameter. Check the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363822/compile-time-conditional-member-function-call-in-c . I want to use constexpr functions (and not variables) because they hide the implementation detail and I can always change it without changing the interface. Anyway I need *something* constexpr. Whether it's a function/struct/variable doesn't really matter

Comment: Anyway, how do I define a boolean which determines whether a given macro is defined? That is the goal

Answer (score 0):

Testing for `C++11` in portable way is done as follows

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

  /* C++11 stuff */

#endif
```

rather than using environment-specific macros such as `HAVE_CXX11`.

I don't think that you can automate the creation of a method that provides a language interface to your preprocessor macro, at least not if the condition is of the form `#ifdef MACRO`, because the pre-processor is not powerful enough for this sort of thing.

Comment: Indeed, the preprocessor is not powerful enough. But other solutions are possible, for example create a C++ header containing constexpr functions/variables in the same way Autotools create config.h